# HC-SR04 not working RPi2 with python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run a HC-SR04 module on my RPi 2 Model B with python, although i have had no success. The wiring seems fine and so does to code but either the pulse is never sent out nor received, can anyone help?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#GPIO Operandi (BOARD / BCM)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Set the GPIO pins
TRIG = 35
ECHO = 37 
# Define the direction in which the pins are working 
# If they send a signal OUT or recieve a signal IN
# ultrasonic sensor pins for TRIG and ECHO
GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)
#Allowing sensor to settle
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
time.sleep(2)
# TRIG HIGH
GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
# TRIG LOW after 0.01ms
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
# Define start time
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
        StartTime = time.time()
# Define end time
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        StopTime = time.time()
# Calculate the difference between the StartTime and the StopTime
TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime
# Multiply by speed of sound
# Divide by  2 for one direction
distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2
print(distance)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the operandi needed to be BOARD and secondly the ECHO needed to be connected to GND